# WPF : Get particular field from ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, combobox, field, observablecollection, datacontext

I have an ObservableCollection named SeiveList. I want all the SeiveIdSize from the list (except the last one as it is of no use) and set the DataContext for a Combobox. I added

```
seiveCmb.DataContext = GlobalUtils.SeiveList;
seiveCmb.DisplayMemberPath = // WHAT SHOULD GO HERE. hOW TO ONLY SHOW SeiveIdSize

// XML 
<ComboBox Name="seiveCmb" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" SelectedIndex="0" ></ComboBox>
```

**EDITED AS PER Sebastian's suggestion :** At present, I just tried out with list for combobox. 
My Seive class :

```
public class Seive : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   // Other Members
   private bool isSelected;

           public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
 }
```

In my Window .xaml file :

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=comboSeives}"
                          x:Key="comboSeivesFiltered"
                          Filter="ComboSeiveFilter">            
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

 <ComboBox Name="seiveCmb" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource         comboSeivesFiltered}}" DisplayMemberPath="SeiveIdSize"
                      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2" SelectedIndex="0"
                      ></ComboBox>
```

In Window .cs file :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Seive> comboSeives { get; set; }

    // Initial original data in Window_Loaded method
    comboSeives = GlobalUtils.SeiveList;

    public void ComboSeiveFilter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        Seive sv = e.Item as Seive;
        // Add items those is != "TOTAL" and isSelected == false
        if (sv.SeiveIdSize != "TOTAL" && sv.IsSelected == false)
            e.Accepted = true;
        else
            e.Accepted = false;
    }
```

If the id is "TOTAL" or isSelected is false (i.e. not added to the grid), then only return true and it will add up in it. With initial all records have isSelected = false.

This is what I have understood from youe explaination and help of [this site](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31). and have implemetned this. But in the runtime, I don't see any thing in the combobox. I tried to debug adding break at filter method, but it is never reached there. Can you point out where I am making mistake from the above code.

aNY HELP IS Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tired `seiveCmb.DisplayMemberPath = "SeiveIdSize";`?

Comment: Can you show an example element of `SeiveList`?

Comment: @nemesv, yes had added DisplayMemberPath also. See the combobox if xaml. But yet no results.

Comment: @StaWho, I don't get what u mean by example element. The contens of SeiveList are :GlobalUtils.SeiveList.Add(new Seive("+10"));
            GlobalUtils.SeiveList.Add(new Seive("+8"));
            GlobalUtils.SeiveList.Add(new Seive());    added in constructor of the Window. When I debug, I see after the line comboSeives = GlobalUtils.SeiveList; comboSeives also has 3 items in it. So things are getting added in it. In ComboSeiveFilter, I added just e.Accepted = true, but that method is never fired at all- a break is added at that method.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want your Collection to be filtered, removing one element. One way to do this is create a CollectionView in your Window.Resources and apply a filter Method - as demonstrated and explained [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=31).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=SeiveList}"
                          x:Name="seiveListFiltered"
                          Filter="MyFilter">

    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

Your code insinuates that in your case the collection is the DataContext of the Window. This must be changed to match your new Resource:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource seiveListFiltered}}"/>
```

Note that this will fill your ComboBox with items that resemble the output of your SeiveItem.ToString()-Method (Actually, I don't know the class name of the Item). Use the `DisplayMemeberPath`-Property to set the name of the Property to display instead.

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="SeiveIdSize" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource seiveListFiltered}}"/>
```

Comment: Good answer - beats filtering in code using linq etc which I was thinking for a sec :)

Comment: @Sebastian, Thanks a lot. With this resource I am looking out for something more. I have SeiveList that contains data of all Seive obj. I have a part, where you select seiveId (Combobox), add its details and that data gets listed in a datagrid. Once I add data to the grid I want that seiveId to be removed from the combo's list. When a record is deleted from the grid, that seiveId should again be added to the combo's list. This is what am looking for. This will redice my validation to keep an eye on which id is added. can you guide me with this too.

Comment: @Tvd, this is very simple. first, give your Seive obj (or a ViewModel wrapping it) a Property "IsAdded". Then generate two CollectionViewSources: One where you filter out those that have IsAdded==true and on where the same value is false. Bind your combobox to one collection and the DataGrid to the other. Notice that your Seive object must implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the filter to notice the change in the value. So, whenever you change IsAdded, the filters do their thing and the UI gets a CollectionChanged-event.

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier, Kindly pls have a look at the code added in question. I have implemented as you have mentioned, but I don't see any results. Can you pls point out where am I going wrong ! Please help me out. Thanks.